# How to implement clock frequency multiplier using VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I am a beginner in VHDL coding.  I am trying to implement frequency multiplier using VHDL.  I have implemented frequency divider, but frequency multiplier is not that easy.  Please give an idea for implementing that.

Answer (score 5):

For implementation in a FPGA, you must use a dedicated FPGA resource like [Phase-Locked Loop (PLL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-Locked_Loop) (see [Altera](http://www.altera.com/support/devices/pll_clock/basics/pll-basics.html) and [Xilinx](https://www.google.com/#q=Phase+Locked+Loop+Xilinx)) or Digital Clock Managers (DCM) (see [Xilinx](http://www.google.com/#q=Digital+Clock+Managers+DCM+Xilinx)) to multiply a frequency.

These resources can create an output frequency based on an input frequency like:

```
f_out = (N / M) * f_in
```

The PLL and DCM resources are device specific, and often very advanced resources, that allows additional control over phase, delay, etc., so take a look at the resources in the device you are using.

Comment: I had 'fun' with a Xilinx DLL once (a long time ago) when we got the sense of its reset input wrong. It turned out that the only effect of holding it in the reset condition was that its phase noise was slightly below spec... that was really hard to find. Once the reset sense was put right it performed perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

A clock frequency can be divided using flip-flops. However, clock multiplication cannot be performed by purely digital circuits. As mentioned by Morten, a PLL unit (which is a hybrid circuit, thus not directly implemented with VHDL) is used for that. PLLs are built-in units in FPGAs, so all that you have to do is to instantiate them.

A detailed example on how to do it is in Appendix G of "Circuit Design and Simulation with VHDL", by V. Pedroni. Several complete examples usign PLLs for clock multiplication in data serializers are also included in that book.