# Digital frequency doubler with a dual edge triggered flip flop in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to implement a digital input frequency doubler. The circuit consists of an XOR2 gate, dual edge triggered flip flop and a couple of buffers.

The frequency-in goes to one of the Xor inputs. The output of the Xor gate goes through a buffer and into the clock signal of the DFF. The output(ussually Q) used in parallel to feed the remaining Xor input and to feedback to the D input of the flip flop through a buffer. finally the output of the doubler is taken from the Xor gate.

I have tested the circuit and it works.I am a novice in VHDL and have very basic knowledge in verilog. I figured i'd analyse it for practice so that i get a feel of VHDL before third year.

Regards 
Stranger

Comment: Sounds interesting. Did you have a question? You might also want to look at SO's [EE site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/), where things like VHDL and Verilog get discussed more often.

Comment: If FPGA is target, then consider using a PLL or DCM; maybe [this question with answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20854563/2352082) can help you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if anyone in the future is suffering the same fate I am here is the ALMOST FINISHED. all you gotta do is find a way of using clk'event in place of if (clk ='1' and clk'EVENT).
Schematic is here

```
    entity freq_doubler is 
PORT (
        vin : in BIT ;
        vout : out BIT );
 end entity freq_doubler;

 architecture rtl of freq_doubler is 
 signal q : bit;
 signal d,clk,buff : bit ;


 begin 
  buff <= (vin XOR q);
  clk <= buff;
  vout <=buff;
p0: process (d,clk) is
    begin
    if (clk ='1' and clk'EVENT)  then
        q <=d;
    end if;
    end process p0;
end architecture rtl;


 configuration freq_doubler_conf of freq_doubler is 
for rtl
end for;
end configuration freq_doubler_conf;
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? It doesn't look like you ever assign a value to `d`. And yes, you just need to make it work on either clock edge. And find a hardware platform with double-edge flip-flops. And prevent timing problems caused by the asynchronous feedback from `q` to `clk`.

Comment: I have built the circuit physically and it works. Here is a schematic http://www.pldworld.com/_xilinx/html/tip/6easy_4.gif . I  have been trying simulate the circuit in VHDL but I keep getting syntax errors.