# higher frequency clock generation in RTL

Tags: fpga

I need develope synthesizable custom verilog code for generating a higher frequency clock from low frequency clock i.e from 50 MHz clock i need to generate 100 MHZ clock . kindly help  how to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pure Verilog solution is not stable, so dedicated FPGA resources must be used.

Please see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20854841/2352082); it applies to Verilog also, even through tagged VHDL.